# How to fix: "The asset path must start with the project source root"?

Tags: nrwl-nx

We have an nrwl/nx project, that we can build on Windows, but it fails on Linux (Ci sytem).

The error is:
`The /root/dev/apps/dmc-svr/src/assets asset path must start with the project source root: apps\dmc-svr\src`

It seems to be a Windows/Linux path issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a Windows like path for the `sourceRoot` property in `project.json`

```json
{
  "sourceRoot": "apps\\dmc-svr\\src",
  "targets": {
    "build": {
      "executor": "@nrwl/node:build",
      "options": {
        "assets": [
          "apps/dmc-svr/src/assets",
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

the fix is to simply replace the backslash `\\` with a slash `\`: `sourceRoot": "apps/dmc-svr/src"`

We guess that this has been generated by some nx-schema.

Answer (score 0):

I've just has this same issue when migrating from the Angular CLI to NX. Turns out I'd switched branches and the `angular.json` file appeared again after migrating to NX. It should be using the NX `project.json` file now so deleting the `angular.json` file fixed it.